# Editing Solr schema.xml in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, solr, schema

I'm using the following plugin to incorporate Solr into Wordpress: https://github.com/mattweber/solr-for-wordpress

The default schema.xml (https://github.com/mattweber/solr-for-wordpress/blob/master/schema.xml) doesn't seem to index the author field properly--I get no results when I search for an author name, but I DO get results when I search for a post name.

There is a field in the schema for author:

```
field name="author" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"
```

but it seems like it isn't correct since I get no results upon searching.

So how can I correct this and ensure that author is properly indexed?

Answer (score 0):

Change the `type` attribute for the author field to something better suited to search, like the `text` type:

```
<field name="author" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" />
```